# How to 'select new' inside Linq lambda expression?

Tags: linq, lambda

How do i do this in one statement vs breaking up in two?

```
 var newpeople= _rep.GetPeople().Where(p=>p.personID).Select(new KindoFPerson...id=p.id etc)
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
var newpeople= _rep.GetPeople().Where(p=>p.personID)
    .Select(p => new KindoFPerson...id=p.id etc)
```

Note the new "`p =>`".